# Column ambiguous in mysql?

Tags: mysql

I was running this query for the last 6 months with no problems on several servers, but today got an error?

```
 error_message: Database query failed: Column 'account_id' in field list is ambiguous
```

Column account_id is ambiguous?

```
$sql_query = "SELECT pricenotifier_criteria.criteria_id , pricenotifier_criteria.`event_id` , pricenotifier_criteria.`ticket_id` , pricenotifier_criteria.`criteria` ,pricenotifier_criteria.account_id ,seller_ids.user_id,seller_ids.seller_id 
FROM pricenotifier_criteria 
INNER JOIN seller_ids 
ON ( pricenotifier_criteria.account_id = seller_ids.account_id ) 
INNER JOIN pricenotifier_users 
ON (pricenotifier_criteria.user_id = pricenotifier_users.user_id ) 
INNER JOIN pricenotifier_pricing_table 
ON ( pricenotifier_users.pricing_id = pricenotifier_pricing_table.pricing_id ) 
WHERE status=1 AND pricenotifier_pricing_table.processing_time = 15 
AND pricenotifier_criteria.user_id = 339  
ORDER BY pricenotifier_criteria.event_id  
LIMIT 2000 
OFFSET 0";
```

I have tried to run this query in sql in phpmyadmin but no error came there ? if i run this via php than i got that error

**APOLOGY TO BE MADE**

I am really sorry in the page where i was running this query i had called another page where other programmer didnt mentioned table prefrix that's why we got this error but all of the guys who replied was right so everyone has almost true answer about (why ambigius error comes). I posted it here because i was sure my query has nothing ambigious and i was right but the other file was running some query and had that error.

Comment: Are you sure that what you have in php is identical with this query?

Comment: I have just copied and pasted this query from php script

Comment: I don't think *this* error message is referring to *that* query, although it could be tidier... oh, the only *potential* ambiguity is `status`

Comment: I think your php code just selects `account_id` without table prefix `pricenotifier_criteria` or `seller_ids`. And this would indeed be ambiguous.

Comment: Can you show us your php code when you prepare and execute your query ?

Comment: I agree whit @Strawberry. The sql that is giving the error is not this one. There is nothing that could cause the mentioned error on this query.

Comment: Have you done any upgrade?Or do you have some custom functions or filters?

Comment: strawberry you were right the error was in other page that was included to this page

Answer (score 0):

Cleaner version of the same thing...

```
 SELECT c.criteria_id 
      , c.event_id
      , c.ticket_id
      , c.criteria
      , c.account_id 
      , s.user_id
      , s.seller_id 
   FROM pricenotifier_criteria c
   JOIN seller_ids s
     ON s.account_id = c.account_id
   JOIN pricenotifier_users u
     ON u.user_id = c.user_id 
   JOIN pricenotifier_pricing_table g
     ON g.pricing_id = u.pricing_id 
  WHERE status = 1 
    AND g.processing_time = 15 
    AND c.user_id = 339  
  ORDER 
     BY c.event_id  
  LIMIT 2000;
```

Answer (score 0):

I bet your php code just selects `account_id` without table prefix `pricenotifier_criteria` or `seller_ids`. Since both tables contain a field `account_id` this would be ambiguous without table prefixes.

Comment: but you see i am putting table prefrex

Answer (score 0):

This error :

> error_message: Database query failed: Column 'account_id' in field list is ambiguous

means that `account_id` is the field of 2 or more tables. As an example :

```
SELECT account_id, other_things
FROM table_account
INNER JOIN table_account2 ON (table_account.account_id = table_account2.account_id)
```

`account_id` is the field of 2 tables : `table_account` and `table_account2`. Then, this is ambiguous, because from which table will the `account_id` supposed to be selected ?

As @strawberry states, the only field that can be ambiguous is `status` in the query you showed us. If you have really this problem, make sure you prefix all your fields in your query like this : `table.field_name`. Then, this will avoid this kind of error.

Comment: pricenotifier_criteria.account_id i am selecting this from pricenotifier  can you see the query again ?

Comment: @user3010908 In your case, `account_id` is from `pricenotifier_criteria` and `seller_ids`. But, you have put the table name in front, so this is ok. Just make sure your query in your PHP code is identical. Also, make sure you put the table name in front of ALL your fields.

Comment: Hello gabriel can you see my question again i have appology